# Query to analyze the cell info from past occurrence of a record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Well this is a bit complex to write down the scenario, but here it is: I have a SQL table which looks like below:

```
TestName | TestStatus | TestDate
--------------------------------------
  test 1 | Failed     | 1-Jun-2014
  test 1 | Not tested | 1-May-2014
  test 1 | Passed     | 1-Apr-2014
  test 2 | Failed     | 7-Jun-2014
  test 2 | Passed     | 3-May-2014
  test 3 | Failed     | 5-Apr-2014
  test 3 | Failed     | 1-Feb-2014
  test 4 | Passed     | 5-Apr-2014
  test 4 | Failed     | 1-Feb-2014
```

I want to write a query which will pick up each distinct TestName (test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4) and do the following:

1. look for the latest status.
2. If latest status is 'failed', then look for the old Statuses for this item.
3. If any of the old status is 'passed' then flag it as "Not first time fail"

So my output will be a new table like this:

```
TestName | First Time Fail?
---------------------------------
test 1   | No
test 2   | No
test 3   | Yes
test 4   | No
```

Can I do it via SQL query?

Comment: does your output need to contain the testdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a SQL query using window functions:

```
select t.TestName, (case when TestStatus = 'Failed' and numpassed = 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by testname order by testdate desc) as seqnum,
             sum(case when TestStatus= 'Passed' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by testname) as numpassed
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```